# understanding mappedBy in grails

Tags: grails

From the grails documentation, I am trying to understand the following example.

[image]

The tables that are created from these two domain definitions are as follows:

[image]

What i don't understand here is what is the purpose of mappedBy which is specified in the Airport domain? Thanks for the help!

Comment: what happens, if you ommit `mappedBy`?

Answer (score 1):

The `mappedBy` is used to know which relation (foreign key column) on the other side that should be used for the `hasMany` relation. It is only necessary if it is not obvious. In the example above, the `flights` relation should use `departureAirports` and `mappedBy` is necessary since `destinationAirport` is also a relation to the `Airport` class/table. If you omit `mappedBy` in this case, it will not be clear which relation to use and you may end up with a relation that is mapped by the wrong foreign key column. You could be lucky that it chooses the correct one but it is not deterministic and it may lead to unexpected behaviour.

The tables generated by the code will look the same without it though. It is the application usage/mapping of the tables that will differ.

Comment: Thanks but i am still confused. You said that the flights relation should use departureAirports and it is necessary but i was thinking flights is a collection of Flight type and Flight has both departureAirport and destinationAirport then why should we just specify flights to be departureAirport? Thanks for the help!

Comment: That is up to the domain logic. In this example airports are only interested in listing departure flights. If the airport would like to list also arrival flights it would need to create a new hasMany relation for the arrival flights. Also this relation needs the mappedBy since it is again ambigous which relation to use.